# Xubuntu 19.04 not available as download for 32 bit PC's but upgrade option is visible from 18.10

Tags: xubuntu, 32-bit

I'm using Xubuntu 18.10 on a 32 bit laptop. As per website of Xubuntu there is no download available for 32 bit PC.
Then Xubuntu automatically is suggesting for an update to new version 19.04.

Should I upgrade? Does it work if I upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official website also says that starting Xubuntu 19.04 does not support 32-bit. I suggest you use the 18.04 LTS version.

Comment: Thanks for reply. If 32 bit PC are not supported why does xubuntu prompt for an "upgrade to next version" . Thanks.

Comment: *"The official website also says that starting Xubuntu 19.04 does not support 32-bit."* Where does it say that?

Comment: http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-cdimage-xubuntu/releases/19.04/release/

Comment: @Karthik Upgrading from 32-bit Xubuntu is still supported, but fresh installations of Xubuntu 19.04 and later support 64-bit processors only.

Comment: Thanks karel for the quick response . I will now update to  19.10 

Comment: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2018-December/004647.html

Comment: Thanks for info. I tried upgrading from a existing  18.04 version. It was aborted with a message that upgrade is discontinued for 32 bit PC. So I have to just continue using 18.04